# Using callbacks but code runs on wrong object

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, concurrency, fragment

I've implemented a callback for running async (using concurrent) HTTP calls (using net) and when they are done they call the complete callback implemented in the caller which is a fragment to update the gui.  In the code calling the complete routine I wrap it in a handler and looper (using main looper) so the complete code can run on the main thread, otherwise I get thread exceptions b/c it can't update the GUI.  Everything else seems to work fine except the following,

I have an activity using navigation drawer and fragments in the main area, they get replaced in.  All other fragments work fine, in one of the fragments I have a view pager that include even more fragments that can be swiped through.  Now a single class is used in the pager and constructed in two different ways for the first/second page that get loaded on init, I pass different init information but it makes the same async calls and passes "this" so the call knows to use the callback to handle responses on the gui.  But these are two seperate objects and pages so the callbacks should be done on the correct object and page.  A viewpager builds both objects in advance current page and next page, but the strange thing is callbacks are called (for both) on the second page only and swiping to the second page it loads/inits properly but the first page doesn't because no callbacks are fired on it.

When I put debugging code in the callback gets called on the second object, never the first.  So both async calls run on the second object (the second view pager page) that isn't shown yet but can be swiped to.  This makes absolutely no sense, when setting the callback I use "this" so it should always be the right instance of the object and I don't see how it's possible the second page/object gets all callbacks...The object gets created, fires off an async call, passes "this" for the callback and implements the callback interface.

Please no suggestions about using android async, there's many reasons we had to do it this way and android docs even recommend concurrent for a variety of reasons.

I'm thinking it has to do with the handler/looper code I'm using, maybe there's something strange going on because of the fragments/view pager and how I'm executing the run on main thread code...otherwise I can't explain it so any information would be appreciated.  I've spent a long time debugging and can't understand what could be going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: First Suggestion: Post Code.

Comment: We kind of need code to figure out what you're talking about.  But if I had to guess, I think you have an object where you passed a callback to and either all instances shared a single callback (which you then overwrote) or you reused the same object (causing you to overwrite the callback).  But without code its a pure guess.

Comment: By swiping through views and playing around with it the fragment seems to initialize properly and work, but not on first load.  Only after swiping through views and causing it to be rebuilt/constructed...so I don't get it.

Comment: There's a lot of code, between the callback patter, the async code, the view pager and custom adapter...it's way to much to post on here.

Comment: Then post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Ok, will do.  And for the view pager/adapter it builds a new fragment for each page.  So the fragment is a new instance and the async call in that fragment uses 'this' so there isn't any cloberring of callbacks.  The async calls are new instances as well (not a static global or singleton) so nothing is re-used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed view pager, instead re-created the look and feel viewpager gave manually via code.  By using fragments (like the rest of the code) and replacing the main container with each new fragment the problem was resolved.  So maybe fragments in fragments in fragments is no good...?

The swiping/look and feel I just re-created myself manually that a view pager gave.

Comment: I think the issue is that run on ui thread could be running it on another object because many fragments implement the callback interface, so if the object dies or goes out of scope and is replaced with a new one the run on ui thread may just be hijacking that one and running it's callback.  Because once in a while I get strange behavior where another fragments callback gets ran and it has nothing to do with a view pager.